# Control within another control in asp.net disables server-side events?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a control which has a button on it.  All the button does is redirect the user to another page.  On this control I have another control which just display some stuff, nothing fancy.  When I click on the button, it does nothing.  When I remove or comment out the other control, the button event works.  Is this by design? I am not sure how to fix it or what is causing it.

ControlA.ascx contains a button with an event like so:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
}
```

ControlA.ascx contains another control inside of it, lets call it ControlB.ascx.

The Button1 click event does not fire when ControlB.ascx is in ControlA.ascx, but when I remove it or take it out, Button1 event fires and it goes to Home.aspx.  This does not only happen for Button1, if I decide to add a second button and create an event for it, if ControlB is in ControlA, the second button event won't fire either.

ControlA.asx markup and code:

```
<div>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Register 2" 
                           onclick="Button1_Click" />
</div>
<div>
    <uc:ControlB ID="ControlB" runat="server" />
</div>

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
}
```

ControlB.ascx markup:

```
<div>
  <p>I am control B</p>
  <p>
     <sbi:SexyLinkButton ID="SexyLinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Go Home" 
                         PostBackUrl="~/home.aspx" />

      <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Register 2" 
                           onclick="Button1_Click" />

</p>
</div>
```

As stated before, Button1_Click does not fire if ControlB is inside ControlA, but if I remove ControlB or comment  it out, Button1_Click fires.

I figured something out:

ControlB.ascx had a button on it called SexyButton ( didn't create this, someone else did, lol) and when I removed that from ControlB, ControlA's button worked.  I put an asp.net Button in controlB and it worked, so it has something to do with the SexyButton control.

If I put an asp.net button on ControB along with the SexyLinkButton, the event for Button1 on ControlB does not work.

SexyLinkButton.cs -  If I put the PostBackUrl on the SexyLinkButton, asp.net button events don't fire.  Here is the code the SexyLinkButton.cs:

```
public class SexyLinkButton : LinkButton
{
    private List<string> Css = new List<string> ();

    public string IconCssClass { get; set; }
    public SizeEnum Size { get; set; }

    public SexyLinkButton()
    {
        Size = SizeEnum.Normal;
    }

    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CssClass)) Css.Add(CssClass);             // User added Css
        Css.Add("sbi-button");                                              // Standard Css for button
        if (Size != SizeEnum.Normal) Css.Add(Size.ToString().ToLower());    // Size Css

        // Nested spans per design and css requirements
        HtmlGenericControl span1 = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
        HtmlGenericControl span2 = new HtmlGenericControl("span");

        // Nested span only for icon
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.IconCssClass))
        {
            HtmlGenericControl btnspan = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
            btnspan.Attributes.Add("class", IconCssClass.Replace(".", string.Empty));
            btnspan.InnerHtml = this.Text;
            span2.Controls.Add(btnspan);
        }
        else
        {
            span2.InnerHtml = this.Text;
        }

        CssClass = string.Join(" ",Css.ToArray());
        this.Text = "";
        span1.Controls.Add(span2);
        this.Controls.Add(span1);

        base.Render(writer);
    }

    public enum SizeEnum
    {
        Normal,
        Medium,
        Large
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't help you without seeing your code.

Comment: Specifically, what parts do you want to see?

Comment: How do u navigate to the other page if you comment out the first control?

Comment: @xaisoft the nothing fancy code :)

Comment: You have the second control(days one) *ON/IN* the same control that has the button as part of it? Or on just the same page? What controls are you talking about(if they are third party), or are they custom?

Comment: I was just saying that when I comment out the control on the page, the event for the button fires and navigates to the other page.

Comment: @curstick- no idea why i put some days lol.  Control A has a button on it. Control B is in Control A.  When Control B is in Control A, the button event does not fire, but when I take out Control B, the button event fires.  They are regular asp.net ascx controls.

Comment: Really, really can't tell you what's happening unless we can see your code.  This isn't by design (that would be silly), it has something to do with your specific controls.

Comment: @womp - ok, I will post the code for the controls.

Comment: recreated your code and it works fine for me. What else could be the reason?

Comment: The markup and code the controls is not that much, let me know if you want to see any other part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's probably happening is that your "SexyLinkButton" control is causing a javascript error that's preventing your button's postback. Check your browser's error console to see if any javascript errors are being generated. Also, try substituting a standard LinkButton control instead of the SexyLinkButton to see if that fixes it.

Edit: looks like it's actually a form issue with the PostBackUrl.

Comment: Yeah, I actually removed the SexyLinkButton and replaced it with an asp.net Button and it worked.

Comment: Button1 is the event that does not fire when SexyLinkButton is there.  SexyLinkButton works fine.

Comment: Were there any javascript errors? Clearly SexyLinkButton is preventing Button1 from firing. Does SexyLinkButton include a form element (ie. when you view the page source)? If so, be aware that you can't nest forms; that might lead to the kind of behavior you're seeing (though I think it usually just throws an error).

Comment: One thing I found out is that if I removed the PostBackUrl property from the sexylinkbutton, everything works. Instead, I added a click event to the SexyLinkButton and everything still works that way, so it is something with the PostBackUrl.

Comment: I will post the code that the creator of SexyButtons created.

Comment: OK, try removing the PostBackUrl from the SexyLinkButton, and instead handle its "onClick" event and redirect to that page, like you are doing for Button1.

Comment: I did that and it works.  Why would the PostBackUrl cause the problem?

Comment: It seems to be overriding the postbacks of the other buttons on the page. Try viewing the source of the page in the browser to see what the generated html is for the form element, and then for each of the buttons.

Another thing you could try is explicitly setting the PostBackUrl on Button1 to an empty string.